# C# Dividing a Matrix into Sub Blocks

Tags: c#, matrix, split, block, divide

i have a matrix came from an image 1600x1600. now i need to assign this matrix into  4x4 blocks. As an example:

```
              00 01 02 03
      IMAGE = 04 05 06 07        BLOCK(i) =   00 01       BLOCK(i+1) = 02 03
              08 09 0A 0B                     04 05                    06 07
              0C 0D 0E 0F
                                BLOCK(i+2) = 08 09        BLOCK(i+3) = 0A 0B
                                             0C 0D                   = 0E 0F
```

1 ) Firstly i dont know the image dimensions , the user opens it. i get it later. my test image 1600x1600.But blocks dimensions are fixed at 4x4. And image dimensions are , lets we agree can be divided with 4 for now...

2 ) I dont know how many blocks going to be.

3 ) I need to acces the row and coloumb of the blocks later because i will be performing mathematical operations with the blocks later... For example , XOR operation with block(n)[x,y] with block(n+1) [x,y].
So this decleration part , this part of the program is very very important.

i stucked this part of the program for 2 weeks i cant continue. Pls help me. İt looks very simple code but.......

My structure is like this , begining part

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("c:\\yavanna.jpg");
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("c:\\yavanna.jpg");

    int width = bmp.Width;
    int height = bmp.Height;
    Color p;
    int[,] alpha_map_int = new int[width, height];
    int[,] red_map_int = new int[width, height];
    int[,] green_map_int = new int[width, height];
    int[,] blue_map_int = new int[width, height];
    int[,] grayscale_map_int = new int[width, height];

    string[,] gray_scale_map = new string[width, height];

    string temp_hexValue;

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            //get pixel value
            p = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);

            //extract pixel component ARGB
            int a = p.A;
            alpha_map_int[x, y] = a;

            int r = p.R;
            red_map_int[x, y] = r;

            int g = p.G;
            green_map_int[x, y] = g;

            int b = p.B;
            blue_map_int[x, y] = b;

            //convert to gryscale
            double grayscale = 0.2126 * red_map_int[x,y] + 0.7152 * green_map_int[x, y] + 0.0722 * blue_map_int[x, y];
            grayscale_map_int[x, y] = Convert.ToInt32(grayscale);
            temp_hexValue = Convert.ToString(grayscale_map_int[x, y]);
            gray_scale_map[x, y] = temp_hexValue;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have got?

Comment: i have all parts of getting grayscale matrix from image as string. i tried "List<string[,]> blocks = new List<string[,]>();" commend but i could not achieve it.

Comment: The least you should show us what the input and maybe the output data structure look like.

Comment: strings really? converting them to int or byte asap is recommended. - Calculating the number of blocks should be simple (16k*16k / 4), then double loop over the input array and fill in the numbers to the appropriate slots.

Comment: Also: Do not [repost the same questions!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52018935/c-sharp-create-matrix-from-image-and-split-it-into-blocks)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Create matrix from Image and Split it into blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52018935/c-sharp-create-matrix-from-image-and-split-it-into-blocks)

Comment: my sturcuture is below

Comment: Ok, something is happening here....

Comment: and also for some reason , inside of the blocks must be hex values. but it is not important for now. i just need to divide the matrix 4x4 blocks , i should be able to use this blocks in loops. like block(i)[ x , y]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a version of jdweng's answer, that generates 4x4 arrays and handles source arrays that don't divide by 4. You can see why he posted a simplified sample. Any bigger and it would be worth using two more loops to populate the 4x4 array.

'image' is the input, 'bytes4x4' is the output.

```
List<List<List<byte>>> bytes4x4 = new List<List<List<byte>>>();

for (int row = 0; row<length-3 ; row += 4)
{
    for (int col = 0; col<width-3; col += 4)
    {
        bytes4x4.Add(new List<List<byte>>()  { 
            new List<byte>() { image[row, col], image[row, col + 1], image[row, col + 2], image[row, col + 3]}, 
            new List<byte>() { image[row + 1, col], image[row + 1, col + 1], image[row + 1, col + 2], image[row + 1, col + 3] }, 
            new List<byte>() { image[row + 2, col], image[row + 2, col + 1], image[row + 2, col + 2], image[row + 2, col + 3] },
            new List<byte>() { image[row + 3, col], image[row + 3, col + 1], image[row + 3, col + 2], image[row + 3, col + 3] }
    });
}
```

This declares and populates 'bytes4x4', which is a long list of two dimensional blocks. Access a block like this:

```
var block100 = bytes4x4[100];
```

And use that to get a pixel:

```
var block100pixelrow1col3 = block100[1][3];
```

or

```
var block100pixelrow1col3 = bytes4x4[100][1][3];
```

Note that these indexs are all zero based, so there's no element [4] in the blocks.

Now I think about it, you might be after a 2-dimensional array of 2-dimensional blocks. If so the code would look like this:

```
var bytes4x4 = new List<List<List<List<byte>>>>();

for (int row = 0; row<length-3 ; row += 4)
{
    var row = new List<List<List<byte>>>();
    bytes4x4.Add(row);
    for (int col = 0; col<width-3; col += 4)
    {
        row.Add(new List<List<byte>>()  { 
            new List<byte>() { image[row, col], image[row, col + 1], image[row, col + 2], image[row, col + 3]}, 
            new List<byte>() { image[row + 1, col], image[row + 1, col + 1], image[row + 1, col + 2], image[row + 1, col + 3] }, 
            new List<byte>() { image[row + 2, col], image[row + 2, col + 1], image[row + 2, col + 2], image[row + 2, col + 3] },
            new List<byte>() { image[row + 3, col], image[row + 3, col + 1], image[row + 3, col + 2], image[row + 3, col + 3] }
    });
}
```

Then you could access a block that is 14 rows down and 23 columns across like this:

```
var block14by23 = bytes4x4[14][23];
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. do this code only declera the blocks or also populate it ?
and how can i reach the blocks , how can i use this code. for example i want to reach the element in the block(byte) 100 [2,4] element. how can i do that.

Comment: This code is perfect. That What i was looking for ages. Thanks very much...

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
       const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.jpg";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Bitmap image = new Bitmap(FILENAME);


            int height = (int)image.Height ;
            int width = (int)image.Width;


            List<List<List<Color>>> bytes = new List<List<List<Color>>>();
            List<List<List<Int32>>> grayscale_map_int = new List<List<List<Int32>>>();


            for (int row = 0; row < height; row += 4)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < width; col += 4)
                {
                    bytes.Add(new List<List<Color>>()  { 
                         new List<Color>() { image.GetPixel(col, row), image.GetPixel(col + 1, row), image.GetPixel(col + 2, row), image.GetPixel(col + 3, row)} , 
                         new List<Color>() { image.GetPixel(col, row + 1), image.GetPixel(col + 1, row + 1), image.GetPixel(col + 2, row + 1), image.GetPixel(col + 3, row + 1)} , 
                         new List<Color>() { image.GetPixel(col, row + 2), image.GetPixel(col + 1, row + 2), image.GetPixel(col + 2, row + 2), image.GetPixel(col + 3, row + 2)} , 
                         new List<Color>() { image.GetPixel(col, row + 3), image.GetPixel(col + 1, row + 3), image.GetPixel(col + 2, row + 3), image.GetPixel(col + 3, row + 3)} , 
                    });

                    grayscale_map_int.Add(new List<List<Int32>>()  { 
                         new List<Int32>() { GetGrayScale(image.GetPixel(col, row)), GetGrayScale(image.GetPixel(col + 1, row)), GetGrayScale(image.GetPixel(col + 2, row)), GetGrayScale(image.GetPixel(col + 3, row))} , 
                         new List<Int32>() { GetGrayScale(image.GetPixel(col, row + 1)), GetGrayScale(image.GetPixel(col + 1, row + 1)), GetGrayScale(image.GetPixel(col + 2, row + 1)), GetGrayScale(image.GetPixel(col + 3, row + 1))} , 
                         new List<Int32>() { GetGrayScale(image.GetPixel(col, row + 2)), GetGrayScale(image.GetPixel(col + 1, row + 2)), GetGrayScale(image.GetPixel(col + 2, row + 2)), GetGrayScale(image.GetPixel(col + 3, row + 2))} , 
                         new List<Int32>() { GetGrayScale(image.GetPixel(col, row + 3)), GetGrayScale(image.GetPixel(col + 1, row + 3)), GetGrayScale(image.GetPixel(col + 2, row + 3)), GetGrayScale(image.GetPixel(col + 3, row + 3))} , 
                    });

                }
            } 


        }
        public Int32 GetGrayScale(Color color)
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(0.2126 * color.R + 0.7152 * color.G + 0.0722 * color.B);
        }
```

Comment: Although OP states it can be divided by 4x4 blocks, I would suggest to test for this restriction.

Comment: Minor point - this is for 2x2 blocks, not 4x4 - but the principle is good.

Comment: Standard image sizes having odd number of rows and columns?

Comment: The example in the posting is 2 x 2 even though the title says 4 x 4.

Comment: since i cant write it , as an example i write 2x2 just to be understood. blocks are 4x4. image is going to be even and dividable with 4.so no float number. now this code also transfer the inside of the image to blocks ? for example how can i reach to block(10)[ 4, 4] element?

Comment: Please can you repeat this code for an image (gray_scale_map[width, height]).
and 4x4 blocks. Thank you

Comment: does this code populate blocks or i need extra loop for this ? And How can i use from here. for example i need to reach block (n) [2,4] element. what should i do.

Comment: int gray_scale = grayscale_map_int[123][2][4];
                    List<List<int>> block = grayscale_map_int[123];

Comment: Just noticed index 4 is not valid.  The indexing of block is 0 to 3. Also be careful get pixel is x, y.  Normal arrays are Row, Col in this case it is Col, Row.